# Running Temporarily Looping Android Code

Tags: android, while-loop, lifecycle, android-anr-dialog

I would like to make an android app that will complete its start up and then run a while loop until the user had completed a certain task. Then the code would run another function to make sure the user has completed the task correctly. How should I be going about this. I have tried putting the while loop in onCreate, onStart, and onResume and in all the while loop runs forever without letting the GUI get drawn, therefore making the task impossible to complete (Also sometimes I get a ANR message). Where should I put the while loop so that it runs right after the start of that activity and doesn't interfere with the startup?

Thanks,

andrewgies17

EDIT 3-31-13 2:45 PST:

So I took RyPope's advice and created a new thread, and am calling a function from the main thread and it doesn't like that. Here is all my code:

` 
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
public EditText pass1, pass2, pass3, pass4;
public int current = 1;
public boolean enteringCode = true;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    pass1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pass1);
    pass2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pass2);
    pass3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pass3);
    pass4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pass4);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            checkInputs();
        }
    }).start();
}

public void checkInputs() {
    while(enteringCode) {
        if(pass1.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
            current = 2;
        }
        if(pass2.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
            current = 3;
        }
        if(pass3.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
            current = 4;
        }
        if(pass4.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
            enteringCode = false;
            System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(pass1.getText().toString() + pass2.getText().toString() + pass3.getText().toString() + pass4.getText().toString()));
            authenticateCode(Integer.parseInt(pass1.getText().toString() + pass2.getText().toString() + pass3.getText().toString() + pass4.getText().toString()));
        }
        if(current == 1) {
            pass1.requestFocus();
        }
        if(current == 2) {
            pass2.requestFocus();
        }
        if(current == 3) {
            pass3.requestFocus();
        }
        if(current == 4) {
            pass4.requestFocus();
        }
    }
}

public void authenticateCode(int code) {

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}
`
 So when this runs and the view tries to request focus it crashes and I get the following logcat output:

`03-31 14:46:54.803: E/AndroidRuntime(10922): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-4197
03-31 14:46:54.803: E/AndroidRuntime(10922): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
03-31 14:46:54.803: E/AndroidRuntime(10922):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4062)
03-31 14:46:54.803: E/AndroidRuntime(10922):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChild(ViewRootImpl.java:730)
03-31 14:46:54.803: E/AndroidRuntime(10922):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:779)
03-31 14:46:54.803: E/AndroidRuntime(10922):    at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4005)
03-31 14:46:54.803: E/AndroidRuntime(10922):    at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:8605)
03-31 14:46:54.803: E/AndroidRuntime(10922):    at android.view.View.onFocusChanged(View.java:3884)
03-31 14:46:54.803: E/AndroidRuntime(10922):    at android.widget.TextView.onFocusChanged(TextView.java:8281)
03-31 14:46:54.803: E/AndroidRuntime(10922):    at android.view.View.unFocus(View.java:3814)
03-31 14:46:54.803: E/AndroidRuntime(10922):    at android.view.ViewGroup.requestChildFocus(ViewGroup.java:530)
03-31 14:46:54.803: E/AndroidRuntime(10922):    at android.view.View.handleFocusGainInternal(View.java:3706)
03-31 14:46:54.803: E/AndroidRuntime(10922):    at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:5402)
03-31 14:46:54.803: E/AndroidRuntime(10922):    at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:5352)
03-31 14:46:54.803: E/AndroidRuntime(10922):    at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:5330)
03-31 14:46:54.803: E/AndroidRuntime(10922):    at com.thirteenbit.driveSafe.MainActivity.checkInputs(MainActivity.java:51)
03-31 14:46:54.803: E/AndroidRuntime(10922):    at com.thirteenbit.driveSafe.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:26)
03-31 14:46:54.803: E/AndroidRuntime(10922):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)`

Anybody got a solution to this predicament?

Comment: `onCreate()` is probably fine but we will have to see your code to know what the problem is. Also, logcat if it is crashing. If it is network stuff then it will need to be done in a background thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably best to create a new [thread](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) so that the start Up doesn't get hung up on the loop.
Try this in the onCreate:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        while(true)
        {

        }
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: so this would allow my operations to run in the background while the startup runs? also, how would i end the tread when im done with it?

Comment: Ok i tried that, now it launches, but when the user completes the activity it is programmed to put another view into focus, and when that happens it crashes and logcat says that only the original thread can touch it's views.

Comment: You can't call a function in the mainActivity and perform actions on the original thread? Try using 
thread.shouldContinue = false;
thread.join();

Comment: so basically i have the new thread that calls a function thats inside the orignal tread like this 
`new Thread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
          checkInputs();
      }
  }).start();`
when checkInputs() is inside the main thread and refers to views and variables from the main UI and the main thread. apparently android doesnt like that and so the logcat gives me this `FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-4167 android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views. `

Comment: Hmm, try this:
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {


    }
});

and hopefully it won't bring you back to your original issue.

Comment: so now i have
`runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
       checkInputs();
      }
  });`

Comment: What is the logcat problem? Same as before?

Comment: no logcat problem..it doesnt complete the startup just like it did the the firstplace...then eventually i get an ANR message

Comment: How about moving this in a different direction, what exactly are you trying to do? Why can't you just set an onClickListener to a button?

Comment: so what i would like to do is have the system sense when the editText has something in it and then automatically move on to the next editText, like when putting in a passcode. so like if you put the first digit in , it automatically moves on the the next edit text for the next digit..im modeling this after the dropbox for android passcode interface if youre firmiliar with it.

Comment: I think you will benefit from looking at how to make a textChanged listener and bind it to your EditTexts. Using a background thread with a for loop just makes everything much more difficult (and introduce a significant overhead).

Comment: i see..so creating the listener would let me just trigger the focus of the next editText when it's set off...interesting...that would let me run it on the main thread without the constant check..ill try that.

Comment: ok that works like a charm. thanks all for the help! was quite a learning experience!

Answer (score 0):

I think your concept is flawed. You probably don't really want a loop to be running.  You want something to happen after the user has completed a task.  You should use a listener that activates after your user has completed their task.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to make some code run in loop you have to run it on new thread, because when do this on main(UI) thread then your application can't update UI because main thread is used by you all the time. So try to make new [thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) or [timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)(it is better).

I hope that this was heplful for you.